# In CSS, you can encode an image in base64?

Tags: css

I just ran into this while looking at the CSS code:

```
background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,LKJSDLKJFSLDJFKDJFLJS......)
```

It looks like the actual image has been encoded, this is a widget that is on a website so it looks like it is done for effeciency reasons so it doesn't have to make a request to a web server.

Is this cross browser safe?
This is news to me!

Comment: Interesting...I hope browsers handle overflow conditions or else hackers could exploit this.

Comment: To be clear, the CSS part is loading an URL in the background image.  The fact that some browsers have support for data URLs is what makes this possible.

Comment: Cool stuff! I never knew about that. Thanks for sharing

Comment: To be clearer, it's loading the image file itself (encoded in base64) in the "url" part of the background value. There is not actually a traditional URL or URI being used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

No, you may not want to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages

Answer (score 2):

It's supported in all major browsers, yes.  However, IE7 and less dont support it, and IE8 needs it to be less than 32K (which shouldn't be a problem).  IE9 does not have this restriction.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your URL must be under 32k for IE8.

Answer (score 0):

There are also hacky ways for doing this for IE6/7 using MHTML

See http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/

Turbine (for PHP) will convert images smaller than 25kb to data URIs or MHTML automatically

See http://turbine.peterkroener.de/docs.php#plugins-datauri